# Sql Database sync error in azure Database Sync Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect my local database with online database. I've followed the full procedure but `Database Sync Group` is showing a log error of following type

```
Database provisioning failed with the exception "SqlException 

Database provisioning failed with the exception "SqlException ID: ebcc6489-1083-4635-aa5e-a34deecb61c1, Error Code: -2146232060 - SqlError Number:18456, Message: Login failed.  

For more information, provide tracing ID ‘3b685498-b462-4bde-b99b-0f1a156369c7’ to customer support."
```

[image]

Moreover hub database is not showing any table to select for `sync` but `sync agent database` is showing up.

Kindly please help me out.

Comment: Could you copy the entire message as text instead of showing a screenshot that crops out the important parts? There's even a copy button right there so that you wouldn't be tempted to take a picture of it. Generally, [screenshots are useless here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/61305).

Comment: now check it i added.kindly please help me you can save my job

Comment: _Message: Login failed_. You need to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to verify the **SQL login** you used to configure the hub database on the sync group has been disabled or the password has been changed.

On the **Azure Database**, provide the SQL Admin login with its current password. If you have provided this information before try to do this again.

Follow these steps:

- Click on the Azure DBClick “Sync to other database”
- Click on the sync group which you have created.
- Click on the databases.
- Click on your hub server.
- Enter your username and current password.
- Try to sync.

Reference: [Configure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure?view=azuresql#to-add-a-database-in-azure-sql-database)